# How to map a Java bean to a XML/CSV with mapping customization

Tags: java, xml, configuration, mapping

Here is the result I try to reach: I have a Java bean, and I'd like to map it to an XML file (the problem with CSV is the same). But I need some configurability in my mapping. Let's take an example to illustrate what I'd like to do, it will be better than a long speech :

```
public class MyBean {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
}
```

I'd like to have the following XML file:

```
<root>
    <valueA>field1</valueA>
    <valueB>field2 field3</valueB>
</root>
```

The difficulty I have is to be able to customize the mapping between my Java bean fields and my XML fields. There is no direct hard-coded mapping, I need a user need to be able to configure the mapping without changing the code.

At the end, I need to generate several XML with different mappings, that I need to be able to configure through a mechanism of mapping a final user can use (maybe through an UI or whatever else).

Is there any Java tool able to reach this goal? Or any other external tool? I could implement this intelligence by myself, but I'd prefer using some existing tool.

Thanks for any help.